# Finding Standard Deviation from Percentages

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

The question is -

> Among American women aged 20 to 29 years, 10% are less than 60.8
>   inches tall, 80% are between 60.8 and 67.6 inches tall, and 10% are
>   more than 67.6 inches tall.17 Assuming that the height distribution
>   can adequately be approximated by a normal curve, find the mean and
>   standard deviation of the distribution.

I know I can find the mean with (60.8+67.6)/2 = 64.2

I am just not sure on how to find the standard deviation with the given percentages. If the percentages were ~ 68, 95, or 99.7 I think I could figure it out

Comment: You are expected to use a z-score table to find how many standard deviations correspond to having $10\%$ outside the bounds.  It is like having $68\%$ within $1 \sigma$.  The table interpolates.

Comment: I'm sorry I looked everywhere @RossMillikan and I still cannot find how to calculate  with the data provided. I'm new to stats so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research and help from a friend, I realized my professor decided never to give us a z-score table.

[image]

Because 67.6 is greater than 90% of the population, search for the value that is closest to .9 on the chart above, in this case, .8997 which would give us a z-score of 1.28

since  = (x - μ) / z  ->  (67.6 - 64.2) / 1.28 = 2.65625

the standard deviation () is 2.65625

Comment: Congratulations-you found it.  I am surprised that your teacher had not given you one.  You will never forget this.

Comment: He wanted us to some software he had also not yet taught us haha. Now I have two resources at my fingertips